# Create Edmx from C# Code - Not from database

Tags: c#, frameworks, entity

Is it possible to generate an Edmx file by creating the collections (schema, conceptual, mappings) and mappings in code and building it up in C#?
Note - I've used EdmGen and EdmGen2 which read from a database to create the Edmx. I want to be able to pass the specific items into the metadata without pointing at a database.

Any ideas appreciated.
thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://huagati.blogspot.com/2010/12/creating-or-modifying-entity-framework.html

Answer (score 2):

Why not use [code first](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-code-first-walkthrough.aspx)? This is essentially what code first does; it inspects the POCO CLR types you have in your project and creates the corresponding conceptual/storage/mappings by convention. You can also configure those conventions through a fluent code API.

When you spin up a code first DbContext, you can also get to the resulting XML-based EDMX (if you really need it) from within it through a [WriteEdmx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696608%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method.

If you don't want Code First to generate a database automatically, you can turn off that ['initializer'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679461%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple dummy db context and use this VS extension to get the EDMX generated http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d